# When to use NLP, NLG and NLU in conversation agents?

Tags: natural-language-processing, comparison, chat-bots, natural-language-understanding

I had read some blogs (like [1](https://medium.com/@narrativesci/natural-language-processing-vs-natural-language-generation-1b2d18dd0b67), [2](https://towardsdatascience.com/nlp-vs-nlu-vs-nlg-know-what-you-are-trying-to-achieve-nlp-engine-part-1-1487a2c8b696) or [3](https://www.houseofbots.com/news-detail/11507-1-which-parameters-separates-nlp-nlu-and-nlg)) about what the difference between all three of them is. I am trying to build an open domain conversation agent using natural language AI. That agent can do casual conversation, like a friend. So, for that, I want to know what is the importance of NLP, NLG, and NLU, so that I can learn that part first.

Answer (score 1):

They're all important. NLP is an umbrella term that includes the other two; NLG is only concerned with generating language, ie transforming some internal data structure into human language. NLU is about processing information contained in language, and putting it into relation with a knowledge base etc.

If you don't know anything about any of these fields, then I suggest your aim is far too optimistic. I work for a company that provides a conversational AI platform for businesses to develop their own agents, and it is a complex area.

If you want to have a quick go and pick up some experience, I suggest you start with [ELIZA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELIZA). Even though this is 'ancient', many modern chatbots still work on the same principles. There are many implementations in a number of programming languages, so you should be able to find one that suits you and you can tinker around with it.